# What is the correct order for including these scripts?

Tags: jquery

I use these scripts, but Iam not sure which of them should be included first and which last ...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jquery/Jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Angular/Source/angular_1_0_3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Angular/JSONMtgs/jsonAngularJs.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Home/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

"jsonAngularJs.js" and "Site.css" are my personal scripts.

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the dependencies. If you have a script that depends on jquery then it will come after jquery same goes for other frameworks. CSS order does not matter. I may be wrong on the css part but you can always try. Most important thing is if you are not using frameworks than don't add them. Less http requests the better your site will perform.

Comment: the problem is I need all of these includes...Bootstrap, jquery,jquery-ui and angular js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Note this. DOM is compiled top to bottom. so first your all style will be renedered.

Place your style in head tag

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Home/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Next in body part your html and then all your script will be rendered. Because why we used javascript is to modify dom and that's why we first need to wait to render our dom properly. so we need to put it last after all DOM is ready.

so now strucure goes like this

```
<body>
     your body content
     html tags
     .
     .
     .

     // you all javascript file goes here
     // First need to load jquery because all the below library depend on jquery
     <script src="~/Scripts/Jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/Jquery/Jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>

     // if you use angular js then you don't need to use jquery because mostly jquery functioanlity included in angular.js library
     <script src="~/Scripts/Angular/Source/angular_1_0_3.js"></script>

     <script src="~/Scripts/Angular/JSONMtgs/jsonAngularJs.js"></script> 

     // no need to use bootstrap js because angular provide directive for bootstrap also. please check this link : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
     <script src="~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the order is right unless you are not experiencing any problems in coding or output.

But as far as i know jquery generally comes first and then bootstrap and all others follow.

May be i am wrong, but the best thing is to try it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Put your custom defined JavaScript files last, as you will need to most likely access the above libraries.